# How to programmatically clear the web browser cache in BlackBerry?

Tags: caching, browser, blackberry

I'm setting up an OTA download for a BlackBerry application.  I have a folder containing a JAD files with multiple COD files, along with a simple HTML download page with a link to the JAD file.  The download works fine the first time for each device, but when I place an updated version (new JAD and COD files) with an incremented `MIDlet-Version:` in the JAD file and download it from the device, the display page for the download still shows the old version, and when I click the download button the dialog asks if I want to replace the old version 1.0 with the new version 1.0.

If I go to options/cache and clear the cache and then reload the download page and click the OTA link, it now correctly shows the new version available as 1.1.  So it seems like my browser on the device is caching the old JAD file.

Since clearing the browser's cache fixes the problem, is there any way I can do this programmatically?  I'm opening the browser instance from my BB app anyway, so it would be easy to do, if possible.  Alternatively, is there any property/attribute I can set in the JAD file that will prevent it from being cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, BlackBerry doesn't allow 3rd party apps to manipulate the browser history or cache. However, a workaround for the problem you are seeing is to add the `Cache-Control: no-cache` HTTP header to the page serving the .jad file. This will force the BlackBerry browser to look for a new version every time.

Comment: I have the no-cache header already in the page serving the JAD file. The problem appears to be that the JAD itself is cached.

Comment: By `page serving the JAD file`, do you mean that when you browse to the actual .jad file the header will be returned, or are referring to the page from which you get to the jad file? If it's the latter, then that would explain why the jad file is still being cached.

Comment: @Laepdjek: by "page serving the JAD file", I mean the page that contains a clickable link to the JAD file. The BB browser is occasionally caching the JAD, so that when I put a new version of the JAD/CODs on my website, when the user clicks on the download link they get a popup asking them about installing the old version that they already have. If this happens, I clear the browser cache and click the link again, and *then* I get the download of the latest version.

Comment: I'm actually avoiding the problem by making sure that each new version of the JAD has a different name (e.g. "MyApp_4_1.jad" instead of "MyApp.jad" every time).

Comment: What if you put the header in the actual jad page?

Comment: Well, a JAD file isn't really a "page" - it's more like an INI file with a bunch of lines in the form of `<key>: <value>` like `MIDlet-Version: 2.3.2011.06.22` etc. The closest thing in it to a cache-control header is `RIM-COD-Creation-Time: 1308735180`, but ironically enough the RIM browser pays no attention to it, which makes sense since it would have to download the file to read that value, and the whole point of caching is to not download anything.

Comment: The jad is just a text file served over HTTP by whatever web server you are running (IIS, Apache, etc), so you can add HTTP headers to it just like any other page. It just happens to have a different content type from html pages. But you can still send the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header, and BlackBerry will then redownload the jad every time (I've tried it, and verified that it works).

Comment: Without knowing what system you're running I can't give you code or configuration instructions that will definitely work in your case, but [here](http://www.jatfq.com/archives/62) is a example of how to do this if you're in a PHP application. Similar concepts would apply no matter how you are serving the jad file.

Comment: @Laepdjek: it's a jsp/servlet on tomcat. All I know how to do is add the JAD file to a dynamic web project in eclipse, export it to a WAR file, and then upload it to amazon web services (they host the app).

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
<title>my web Page</title>
</head>
<body>      
</body>
</html>
```